# how to upload a web application to free server

Tags: netbeans

I am using net-beans 7 and I wrote a server said app on java with db.
Now I want to upload it to free global server.
I tried amazon but need a credit card.
Tried to work with Google app engine but have problems with net-beans and Google configurations. 
Can you give me a link for simple way to load my app to free server and how it will work with the db that I wrote that works with derby.

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Amazon Web Services Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/).

Another option is [jelastic.com](http://jelastic.com/) (I didn't test it yet). They offer free use for small applications:

> Starts free: That's right! If you want to deploy a demo for your
>   customers, deploy a small application for you and your friends, or
>   experiment and deploy an app for internal QA, it won't cost you a
>   penny!

Comment: to register their i need a visa.can you tell other service?